# Exponential fit to data using Scipy: Runtime error fix?

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis

I am trying to do an exponential fit to  some experimental data results, I have 6999 rows in each of my two columns. I have assigned the time to the x and the results to the y axis. I tried using scipy.optimize.curve_fit() with my data arrays but it produces a runtime error. I would highly appreciate knowing how I can get rid of the error or how I can code this in a different way, should my parameters be what produces the error.
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize
df =pd.read_csv("output.txt") #reads dataframe into our program
print(df) #to make sure this is what we want
x = np.array(df["t.timestep"]) #gets the data points and defines the timestep as x axis
print(x) #just checking
y = np.array(df["t.cTNF"]) #gets the data points and defines them as y axis
print(y) #just checking
sp.optimize.curve_fit(lambda t,a,b: a*np.exp(b*t), x, y) #should fit the line perfectly
```

It produces the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\kimst\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 789, in curve_fit
    raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)

RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 600.
```

Please help, I have a deadline and am completely stuck, thanks for reading :)

Comment: I would try to confine the paramater space either using some initial values by setting `p0` and/or setting parameter boundaries by setting `bounds` in the `curve_fit()` call,  check [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for details on how to use these properly.

Comment: Can you share the data to fit?